# Spring 5: NullBean ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean method that conditionally returns either a valid initialized bean or a null value if a condition is not satisfied. It looks like below:

```
@Bean
public MyBean myBean() {
  if(this.activated) {  // decides if the bean is needed
    return new MyBean();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This works without any issues when I am using the 3.2.8.RELEASE version of Spring. However, when I run this code with Spring 5, I get a class cast exception where this bean gets used, with a message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean cannot be cast to com.myproject.MyBean
```

where `NullBean` appears to have been introduced in Spring 5.

I am restricted to using Spring 3.x at compile time, however I would also like to make the code executable in a Spring 5 environment with little or no code changes if possible.

I have thought of using the Profile annotation, however, are there other simpler and quicker approaches that can be used instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't return `null` from a `@Bean` method that is a very bad idea and potentially dangerous. You should add a configuration class (or the bean) conditionally but with Spring 3.2 that is a bit hard, but not impossible, to do.